# How to add rule with IPTables.Net to iptables in real system with .NET 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, iptables

I have a [.NET 6 Web API application](https://github.com/BSVN/IpTables.Api/pull/18) and I want to edit my iptables rule in hosted system. (the system that Web API run on it)

I have rule like below

```
-A INPUT -m tcp  --protocol tcp --source 2.2.2.2 --destination 1.1.1.1 --source-port 111 --destination-port 222 --jump DROP
```

I try this rule in `iptables` command in bash and work correctly, but when I try to create rule for this like below

```cs
IpTablesRule rule = IpTablesRule.Parse($"-A  INPUT  -m tcp--protocol tcp --source 2.2.2.2 --destination 1.1.1.1 --source-port 111 --destination-port 222 --jump DROP", null, chains);
```

and then try to add to system like below

```cs
ipTablesSystem = new IpTablesSystem(system: new LocalFactory(), tableAdapter: new IPTablesBinaryAdapter());
inputChain = ipTablesSystem.GetChain(table: Table.FILTER, chain: Chain.INPUT, ipVersion: (int)IpVersion.V4);
inputChain.AddRule(rule);
```

No any error rise on system or something like that, but after I try to see system rules with bash (cli) with `iptables -L` I do not see my rules

Why my rule does not exist in system? and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please don't create unrelated tags. There's no such thing as `c#-iptables`. This only creates noise

Comment: Besides, it would be *very* strange if a web application could make system modifications or worse, modify firewalls. That's what every hacker wishes. Web apps run under restricted  accounts that typically can't even access folders outside the web site, much less open firewall ports

Comment: In any case, the source code shows that `inputChain.AddRule` adds an object to a collection, it doesn't execute `iptables` at all. The `IPTablesLibAdapterClient.AddRule` does. Don't rush to use it though without understanding what's going on because you could end up causing serious problems. Let the deployment script take care of network setup.

Comment: Above code does not publish yet on PR, I refer to project, for better explanation. many web base remote iptables project exist for example https://github.com/palner/iptables-api

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that web apps can't modify firewalls (just dare ask the machine's admin what you tried) and `inputChain.AddRule` doesn't execute anything. API doesn't mean "Web" or "Remote". Yes, there are a lot of libraries but they only work if *the executing account* has permission to make modifications. And web apps should never, ever have such permissions

Comment: Even from the command line, you need to use `sudo` to make modifications, or [give explicit modification permisssions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/624035/proper-way-to-give-a-binary-permissions-to-use-iptables-without-sudo) which require root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for bad using of API, the correct way is like below

```cs
IpTablesRule rule = IpTablesRule.Parse($"-A  INPUT  -m tcp --protocol tcp --source 2.2.2.2 --destination 1.1.1.1 --source-port 111 --destination-port 222 --jump DROP", null, chains);

var ipTablesSystem = new IpTablesSystem(system: new LocalFactory(), tableAdapter: ipTablesAdapter);

IIPTablesAdapterClient table = ipTablesSystem.GetTableAdapter((int)IpVersion.V4);

table.AddRule(rule);
```

The note is, you must get table from `IpTablesSystem` and add or remove rulse from table.